# Flutter TextField height not increasing

Tags: flutter

I am trying to increase my text field height but it's not increasing I already try wrapping with the container and increase the height of the container but it just increases the background height not text field height.
Also maxLines is working but needs to increase by height so I can add some shadows in container

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/screens/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:mytravel/screens/guidePlacePage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

class addPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _addPostPageState createState() => _addPostPageState();
}

class _addPostPageState extends State<addPostPage> {
  File _image;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEDF0F6),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 75, right: 10, left: 10),
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              getImage();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 400.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 5),
                                    blurRadius: 8.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: _image == null
                                      ? AssetImage("assets/images/post0.jpg")
                                      : Image.file(_image),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 200, //here you can see try to increase height
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                      child: TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                          ),
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Your short story of image',
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `contentPadding` controls the height of the `TextField` if you want to increase the height of your text then you would alter the `height` property in `TextStyle`

```
 TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(height: 4 // controls the height on main text
                      ),
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: // Text Field height
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        height: 4, //Controls the height of the hint text
                      ),
                      errorStyle:
                          TextStyle(), // Controls style of error message
                      counterStyle:
                          TextStyle(), //Controls style of the counter if you have one
                      helperStyle:
                          TextStyle(), //Controls style of the helper message
                      labelStyle:
                          TextStyle(), //Controls style of the label message
                      prefixStyle:
                          TextStyle() //Controls the style of the prefix
                      ),
                ),
```

let me know if this works

Comment: If we add height in text style then hint text is going down.

Comment: there a separate ```hintStyle``` that controls that add edited my answer above hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

**First Option: (Make sure to match the height)**

```
TextField(
    style: TextStyle(
        height: 1.5,   // change this to reflect the effect
        fontSize: 20.0
    ),
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        height: 1.5, //Controls the height of the hint text
    ),
)
```

**Second Option:**

```
TextField(                                
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0),
    )
)
```

**Plus** `wcyankees424` answer provides more options, even for success,error etc. hints.

Comment: If we add height in text style then hint text is going down.

Answer (score -1):

Read this page please:

> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html

As it is described you need add a `height property` for text. So you need add this line after font size:

```
height:2.0;
```

When height is null or omitted, the line height will be determined by the font's metrics directly, which may differ from the fontSize. When height is non-null, the line height of the span of text will be a multiple of fontSize and be exactly fontSize * height logical pixels tall.